# How to deploy nextjs developed application using Custom Server and PM2?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have developed an application in nextjs and now trying to deploy my nextjs application with the approach of a custom server. I have tried many times but it has a lost of issue.
Build is successful but linux (Debian) server doesn't run it the compiled release. I followed the tutorial from nextjs site.

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

========================================package.json==================================
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
  "dev": "node server.js",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
}
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
        "next": "11.0.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",      
        "swr": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "7.29.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1"
    },
}
```

```
  ______________________server.js_______________
   // server.js
   const { createServer } = require('http')
   const { parse } = require('url')
   const next = require('next')

   const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
   const app = next({ dev })
   const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

   app.prepare().then(() => {
     createServer((req, res) => {
       // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to 
    `url.parse`.
       // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
       const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
       const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

       if (pathname === '/a') {
         app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
       } else if (pathname === '/b') {
         app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
       } else {
         handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
       }
     }).listen(3000, (err) => {
       if (err) throw err
       console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
     })
   })
```

What is the proper and correct way to deploy the nextjs application ?
I have done almost everything but It might be some glitch in understanding or in server configurations or deployment.

Thank you. Help is appreciated

Comment: You need to run your `server.js` not `next`. Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server#:~:text=Then%2C%20to%20run%20the%20custom%20server%20you%27ll%20need%20to%20update%20the%20scripts%20in%20package.json%2C%20like%20so%3A

Comment: Hi, thank you. I forgot the above. Now i have added this. Can you metion all steps so that i could compare my steps as well.